# Loading the contents of an iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to load the entire content of a child iframe upon some action in the parent frame. I am using jQuery and I am trying to avoid using `<form>` tag, setting up bunch of hidden `<input>` tags and submitting it. instead, I want to use something similar to jQuery's:

```
.load(url, data,function(response){...})
```

or perhaps

```
.post(url, data,function(response){...})
```

so far I tried the 'post' method and tried to use jQuery's `.contents()` method to change the contents of my iframe with the response that I get but the problem is that i need to change the entire content (ie the whole document) of the iframe and `.contents()` method returns the document object of the iframe. all I can do is to change the content of the document (ie say `<head>` or `<body>`). note that my iframe initially has no `src` attribute so initially there is no content to it.

Comment: Why don't you use a `<div>`, and load the contents to it with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

Set the SRC of the iframe:

```
$('#someIframe').attr('src','http://....')
```

Comment: thanks but what would be the URL of the `src`? I am using response dynamically to load the content of the iframe, in fact, the entire content of iframe should be the entire response